# ScrollView: how to disable scrolling in one direction?

Tags: react-native

I have a `ScrollView` which I want to be able to refresh on pull, but other than this, I don't want it to be scrollable.

Is there a way to prevent it from being scrolled only when the user swipes up (and not down)?

React Native: 0.67
React: 17.0.2

Comment: have you tried RefreshControl?

Comment: This is already what I'm using for the refresh on pull. Now I'm trying to prevent the swipe up.

Answer (score 0):

try scrollEnabled={false} and nestedScrollEnabled={false}

```
<ScrollView
  scrollEnabled={false}
  nestedScrollEnabled={false}
>
  {children}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This would prevent all scrolling whatsoever, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it just blocked all scrollings of any sort, when I just want to disable the scroll down

Comment: can you please check this code in expo, I've tried to simulate your issue
https://snack.expo.dev/Ykl7Wxepe

Comment: Again, I feel like your example shows a ScrollView where it is impossible to refresh on pull... I still want to keep that enabled, but just to disable the scroll down / swipe up. Is there something I missed in your example?